# Print a list of lists as a table in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, formatting

I've a list,

```
L = [['First', 'Last', 'GPA', 'Major', 'Drops'],
['Jane', 'Doe', '3.5', 'CS', '2'], ['Joe', 'Doe', '2.0', 'CpE', '0'],
['Todd', 'Brown', '3.88', 'CS', '5'], 
['Mike', 'Smith', '3.88', 'CS', '5']]
```

And I've to print it in a table like:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------
    |     First|      Last|       GPA|     Major|     Drops|
    --------------------------------------------------------
    |      Jane|       Doe|      3.50|        CS|         2|
    |       Joe|       Doe|      2.00|       CpE|         0|
    |      Todd|     Brown|      3.88|        CS|         5|
    |      Mike|     Smith|      3.88|        CS|         5|
```

My code is so far:

```
    L = [['First', 'Last', 'GPA', 'Major', 'Drops'],
     ['Jane', 'Doe', '3.5', 'CS', '2'],
     ['Joe', 'Doe', '2.0', 'CpE', '0'],
     ['Todd', 'Brown', '3.88', 'CS', '5'],
     ['Mike', 'Smith', '3.88', 'CS', '5']]
count1 = 1
while count1 < len(L):
    L[count1][2] = float(L[count1][2])
    L[count1][4] = int(L[count1][4])
    count1 += 1
h_line = 56 * '-'
first_line = "|"
print (h_line)
s = " "
w = 10
for i in range(len(L[0])):
    str1 = (s*(w - len(L[0][i])) + "%s|" % L[0][i])
    first_line = first_line + str1
print(first_line)
print(h_line)
a = 1
while a < len(L):
    second_line = "|"
    for j in range (len(L[a])):
        if type(L[a][j]) == str :
            str2 = (s*(w - len(L[a][j])) + ("%s|" % L[a][j]))
            second_line = second_line + str2
        elif type(L[a][j]) == float :
            str2 = (s*(w-4) + ("%.2f|" % L[a][j]))
            second_line = second_line + str2
        elif type(L[a][j]) == float :
            str2 = (s*(w-1) + ("%i|" % L[a][j]))
            second_line = second_line + str2
    print (second_line)
    a = a + 1


print (h_line)
```

But my output looks like:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------
    |     First|      Last|       GPA|     Major|     Drops|
    --------------------------------------------------------
    |      Jane|       Doe|      3.50|        CS|
    |       Joe|       Doe|      2.00|       CpE|
    |      Todd|     Brown|      3.88|        CS|
    |      Mike|     Smith|      3.88|        CS|
    --------------------------------------------------------
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I think you have twice `elif type(L[a] [j])  == float`. The second time should be `int`

Comment: Thank you, it was obviously a printing error...lol

Answer (score 8):

Holy crud is this ever the wrong way to go about this!!! Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)

```
L = [['First', 'Last', 'GPA', 'Major', 'Drops'],
     ['Jane', 'Doe', '3.5', 'CS', '2'], ['Joe', 'Doe', '2.0', 'CpE', '0'],
     ['Todd', 'Brown', '3.88', 'CS', '5'], 
     ['Mike', 'Smith', '3.88', 'CS', '5']]

def display_table(rows):
    template = "|{:>10}|{:>10}|{:>10}|{:>10}|{:>10}|"
    horiz_rule = "-" * 56
    header = rows[0]
    print(horiz_rule)
    print(template.format(*header))
    print(horiz_rule)
    for row in rows[1:]:
        print(template.format(*row))
    print(horiz_rule)

display_table(L)
```

If you need to be able to programatically assign column widths, you can use an extra `{` and `}` to escape the outer formats, e.g.

```
template = "|{{:>{0}}}".format(some_width) * num_columns + "|"
## if some_width is 10 and num_columns is 5, 
## results in the same template as above. Then you can do:
horiz_rule = 1 + some_width * (num_columns + 1)
```

As a working example, Maybe you wanted to extend each column to a minimum of 10 spaces, but wanted to align to the longest element in that column plus 1.

```
def display_table(rows):
    # might want a sanity check here to make sure the table is square
    num_columns = len(rows)
    template = "|{{:>{}}}" * len(rows[0]) + "|"
    header = rows[0]
    # zip(*iterable) is a good recipe for aligning columnwise
    column_lengths = [max(10, max(map(len, col)) + 1) for col in zip(*rows)]
    finished_template = template.format(*column_lengths)
    hr = "-" * (sum(column_lengths) + num_columns + 1)
    print(hr)
    print(finished_template.format(*header))
    print(hr)
    for row in rows[1:]:
        print(finished_template.format(*row))
    print(hr)
display_table(L)
```

results in:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|     First|      Last|       GPA|     Major|     Drops|
--------------------------------------------------------
|      Jane|       Doe|       3.5|        CS|         2|
|       Joe|       Doe|       2.0|       CpE|         0|
|      Todd|     Brown|      3.88|        CS|         5|
|      Mike|     Smith|      3.88|        CS|         5|
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Or if you add a student whose last name is "SomeReallyLongName":

```
L.append(['Foo','SomeReallyLongName','2.0','Mus','10'])
display_table(L)
## OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------
|     First|               Last|       GPA|     Major|     Drops|
------------------------------------------------------------------
|      Jane|                Doe|       3.5|        CS|         2|
|       Joe|                Doe|       2.0|       CpE|         0|
|      Todd|              Brown|      3.88|        CS|         5|
|      Mike|              Smith|      3.88|        CS|         5|
|       Foo| SomeReallyLongName|       2.0|       Mus|        10|
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Looks like that last bit has an off-by-one error in calculating the horizontal rule. It looks good to me, but obviously it's off (by one!) I'll leave squashing that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

Just an alternative, maybe not the case, but could be useful.

> **pip install tabulate**

**Note:** I've get some errors installing with pip or easy_install.
Succeed to install it by downloading tabulate 0.7.3.tar.gz
and install it with: `python setup.py install`

---

### See it in action (Your case):

```
from tabulate import tabulate

L = [['First', 'Last', 'GPA', 'Major', 'Drops'],
['Jane', 'Doe', '3.5', 'CS', '2'], 
['Joe', 'Doe', '2.0', 'CpE', '0'],
['Todd', 'Brown', '3.88', 'CS', '5'], 
['Mike', 'Smith', '3.88', 'CS', '5']]

print tabulate(L[1:], headers = L[0],tablefmt="grid")
```

#### Output:

```
>>> 
+---------+--------+-------+---------+---------+
| First   | Last   |   GPA | Major   |   Drops |
+=========+========+=======+=========+=========+
| Jane    | Doe    |  3.5  | CS      |       2 |
+---------+--------+-------+---------+---------+
| Joe     | Doe    |  2    | CpE     |       0 |
+---------+--------+-------+---------+---------+
| Todd    | Brown  |  3.88 | CS      |       5 |
+---------+--------+-------+---------+---------+
| Mike    | Smith  |  3.88 | CS      |       5 |
+---------+--------+-------+---------+---------+
>>>
```

> **Bibliography:**
>   tabulate 0.7.3 : Python Package Index http://goo.gl/OkEF5E